# Rails Spree no longer working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a legacy project with Rails 2.3.8, Spree 0.7.0.  Earlier today we had to restart Apache and Rails and now I cannot access Spree login/admin.  This is on production.  What next steps should I take?

Comment: Can you give snapshot of what error are you getting

Comment: Never mind, it was a problem with the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL certificate expires, Spree will not work.

Comment: Yep thats right for a temp solution you can uncheck ssl in configuration for production